# anova.merMod recalculates models using REML = FALSE, where to find the reference?

Tags: r, lme4

I have been using the `anova.merMod` function from `lme4` package to obtain p-values for fixed effects through likelihood ratio tests for a scientific publication (most reviewers still demand p-values in my field). I noticed that the `anova.merMod` function recalculates the `lmer` functions using `REML = FALSE` (see the example below), which is an incredibly nice feature forcing less acquainted users to do the test right. However, I have been trying to read most of the documentation for `lme4` package and cannot find that a notation of this feature (for instance, see `?anova.merMod`, which directs the user to `?vcov.merMod`). This makes me confused.

Question: **Why is this feature not clearly mentioned in the documentation?** Have I understood it wrong, perhaps?

Ps. there seems to be a question about this on the [R-mailing lists](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2008q3/001326.html), but the answers make me even more confused.

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)

reml <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
noreml <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy, REML = F)

reml0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
noreml0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ (Days | Subject), sleepstudy, REML = F)

## Returns similar likelihood ratio test statistics:
(a <- anova(reml, reml0))
(b <- anova(noreml, noreml0))

## Not identical though
identical(a, b)
[1] FALSE
```

**EDIT:** `sessionInfo`: `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)`, `lme4_1.0-5`

Comment: I'm not convinced the answers aren't the same: `identical` will return `FALSE` if any floating-point numbers aren't exactly the same **or** if any name of any variable differs.  Can you take a look at the actual values of the returned elements of interest and see if they differ by more than machine precision?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Testing with `all.equal` reveals that only name attributes differ. So, you are correct.

Comment: Fixed effects and anova results are the same on displayed precision between REML and ML models. Random effects differ. If I do `identical(a$AIC, b$AIC)` I get `FALSE`, `identical(format(a$AIC,digits = 10), format(b$AIC,digits = 10))` is `TRUE` and `identical(format(a$AIC,digits = 13), format(b$AIC,digits = 13))` is `FALSE`. Are digits to 13th decimal reliable in R?

Comment: Now, Largh,  you should know the rules about binary precision in *any* computing language!  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Haha! I am a biologist, not a computer scientist, but I guess you are right. I should know that. Never needed more than 2 decimals in my data output, though. I guess this `format(1/3, digits = 17)` means that R is reliable to 16th decimal?

Comment: for what it's worth, `all.equal(a$AIC,b$AIC)` is `TRUE` (`all.equal()` uses a sensible defaulttolerance of `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as of recent versions of `lme4`, this *is* documented (albeit way down in the details) in `?anova.merMod` (emphasis added):

> ‘anova’: returns the sequential decomposition of the contributions
>             of fixed-effects terms or, for multiple arguments, model
>             comparison statistics.  **For objects of class ‘lmerMod’ the
>             default behavior is to refit the models with ML if fitted
>             with ‘REML = TRUE’**, this can be controlled via the ‘refit’
>             argument. See also ‘anova’.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Roland for doing the legwork,  I'm posting my comment as the answer.

I'm not convinced the answers aren't the same: identical will return FALSE if any floating-point numbers aren't exactly the same or if any name of any variable differs. Can you take a look at the actual values of the returned elements of interest and see if they differ by more than machine precision? –

Roland ran the test and found that the only difference is the `name` attributes.

Comment: I am confused with the double negative in your answer. Does it mean that you are convinced that the answers are the same?

Comment: Well,  *now* I am :-)